# Get params for category and page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, app-router

I use this on my blog homepage to have pagination. The pages are like url/?page=2 etc.

```
export default async function HomePage({
    searchParams,
}: {
    searchParams: {[key: string]: string | string[] | undefined};
}) {
    const DataPosts = await getPostsNumber();
    const PostsNumber = DataPosts.postCount;

    const page = getNumericParam(searchParams.pagina, 1);
    const limit = getNumericParam(searchParams.numar, 10);
```

Works like a charm. Now i'm trying to do the same for categories pages. Here I already have params to get the category name. How can i add the ones for pagination ?

```
export async function generateMetadata({params}: {params: {category: string}}) {
    const slug = params.category;
```

I tried this:

```
export default async function Page({
    params,
}: {
    params: {category: string; [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined};
}) {
    const slug = params.category;

    const DataPosts = await getPostsNumber(slug);
    const PostsNumber = DataPosts.categories[0].count;

    const page = getNumericParam(params.pagina, 1);
    const limit = getNumericParam(params.numar, 10);
```

But params always returns "{ category: 'name' }" and no page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Next.js `app` router, you can retrieve the url query param using:

```
export default async function Page({
    params,
    searchParams,
}: {
    params: { category: string };
    searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
}) {
    const slug = params.category;

    const DataPosts = await getPostsNumber(slug);
    const PostsNumber = DataPosts.categories[0].count;

    const page = getNumericParam(searchParams?.pagina, 1);
    const limit = getNumericParam(searchParams?.numar, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks! The thing is would like to keep the page a server component. Any way with this?

Comment: Have updated my answer. Can you check if works for you?